# how can i use jpeg_mem_src, jpeg_mem_dest in libjpeg-turbo?

Tags: c++, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

libjpeg8 include are those two functions, but in libjpeg-turbo has the following:

```
 //jconfig.h
 #define JPEG_LIB_VERSION 62
```

...

```
//jpeglib.h
#if JPEG_LIB_VERSION >= 80
/* Data source and destination managers: memory buffers. */
EXTERN(void) jpeg_mem_dest JPP((j_compress_ptr cinfo,
                   unsigned char ** outbuffer,
                   unsigned long * outsize));
EXTERN(void) jpeg_mem_src JPP((j_decompress_ptr cinfo,
                  unsigned char * inbuffer,
                  unsigned long insize));
#endif
```

if i try to use "JPEG_LIB_VERSION 80" i'll get the following:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_mem_src referenced in function ...

so, how can i use those functions if it possible? do i need compile some package of libjpeg-turbo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precompiled .lib and .dll files only support the version 6 functions. You need to compile your own library. Pass the `-DWITH_JPEG8=1` flag to CMake to get those two functions.

Comment: oh, but i found just precompiled version, can you type link where can i find sources?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/files/1.2.0/libjpeg-turbo-1.2.0.tar.gz/download

Comment: huuh :) coped everyone file separated, installed cmake, installed nasm - and i'm done. thanks so much

Comment: If you don't want to use CMake run configure with the flag `--with-jpeg8`. As described here: http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/x2go-dev/2012-January/003234.html