# How to setup jpeglib with MS Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: opencv, libjpeg

I try to use the well known "jpeglib" now available in [version 9](http://ijg.org/files/jpegsr9.zip).

**Overview**: I am a programming starter in C using *MS Visual C++ 2010 Express* and read a C-book finally. My goal is to compress a RGB(.bmp)-file into JPEG. So I downloaded the *jpeglib* (v9), read all the install and so on *.txt-files. It was possible to compile the C-files to get *cjpeg.exe*, *djpeg.exe*, *jpeg.lib* and so on.

After this success I tried to use the *example.c* to get deeper into the jpeg and to control the compression. -> It did not work. Then I tried to use the jpeglib included in OpenCV. Same non working result, while the OpenCV code samples are compiled successfully.

I googled lots of samples, problem solutions and tips how to use jpeglib. Most helpful information I found here. But in the result I was still not able to compile my own jpeg-tool or example.c (rewriting the `write_JPEG_file()` function ).

**Question**: What in the basics could be wrong, when every other programmer just uses `#include "jpeglib.h"` in their codes to run the jpeg functions successfully? For me including this file seems not to be enough. Because of that I have to ask you and to relaunch a one year old [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240447/how-to-use-jpeglib) that also did not helped solving my probs. I can not give you a specific error message because of multiple attempts to solve those issues.

Here is my current **MS-VC++2010 config** for using OpenCV 2.4.6:

1. C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories:

   - C:\opencv\build\include
   - C:\opencv\build\include\opencv
   - C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2
   - C:\opencv\include
   - C:\opencv\include\opencv
   - C:\opencv\include\opencv2
   - C:\opencv\3rdparty\libjpeg
2. Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories:

   - C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib
3. Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies:

   - opencv_core246d.lib
   - opencv_imgproc246d.lib
   - opencv_highgui246d.lib
   - opencv_ml246d.lib
   - opencv_video246d.lib
   - opencv_features2d246d.lib
   - opencv_calib3d246d.lib
   - opencv_objdetect246d.lib
   - opencv_contrib246d.lib
   - opencv_legacy246d.lib
   - opencv_flann246d.lib
   - jpeg.lib [this I added into *C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib*]

At last some threads I have already read:

- [Compressing IplImage to JPEG using libjpeg in OpenCV - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443390/compressing-iplimage-to-jpeg-using-libjpeg-in-opencv)
- [Compressing IplImage to JPEG using libjpeg in OpenCV - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448957/compressing-iplimage-to-jpeg-using-libjpeg-in-opencv)
- [Need help in reading JPEG file using libjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616216/need-help-in-reading-jpeg-file-using-libjpeg)
- [how can i use jpeg_mem_src, jpeg_mem_dest in libjpeg-turbo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070473/how-can-i-use-jpeg-mem-src-jpeg-mem-dest-in-libjpeg-turbo)

If there is something missing you want to know I will do my best to add this information!

EDIT - Some error messages:

```
1>jpeg_coder.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""unsigned char * image_buffer" (?image_buffer@@3PAEA)".

1>jpeg_coder.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""int image_height" (?image_height@@3HA)".

1>jpeg_coder.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol """int image_width" (?image_width@@3HA)".
```

First symbol should be typedefed in `jpeglib.h` as `JSAMPLE FAR *JSAMPROW`,
second and third are defined in `rdjpgcom.c` as `unsigned int image_height, image_width;`

Maybe, with a lot of luck, I figured out what is need to be done to get jpeglib running. In the current state I have to check and double check whether my problem solution is correct or not. At this point thank you very much for your attention for my issues. As soon as I am sure with the solution I will post it.

**Problem Solution**: I did not setup OpenCV correctly for using jpeglib. The mistake I made was to link the wrong *.lib-file. The proper file for linking is `libjpegd.lib`. Too bad that jpeglib v6.2 is included in OpenCV 2.4.6 instead of v9. The hint to add `HAVE_JPEG` to use jpeglib functions inside OpenCV I ignored completely. **For now the problem is solved.**

Comment: The question is so long, but you didn't write exactly how `It did not work`

Comment: Sorry for the long question! _It did not work_ means several declarations or functions are missing which are located in `jpeglib.h`, `jdatadst.c`, `jcapimin.c` and many more files. I did not even figure out which files are necessary to get are compilable set of files (minimal configuration).

Comment: To get answer to your question, you need to provide error messages - compiler or linker errors, runtime crash information etc.

Comment: opencv already comes with libjpeg on board (3rdparty), so why roll your own ? all you'd need to do is `imwrite("my.jpg",img);` and you're done.

Comment: I noticed that OpenCV comes with jepglib. This is why my current concentration is focus on it. Somewhere in the Net is written: to activate jpeglib in OpenCV `HAVE_JPEG` has to be added to `highgui.h`. But this file is existing four times and adding `#define HAVE_JPEG` to them changes nothing. I do not know if I use this command correct. Futher more I do not know how to manipulate the OpenCV-jpeg-coding-with-activated-jpeglib for example to modify the DCT...

Comment: Are these variables from your program? It looks like you need to learn how to use `extern` C keyword.

Comment: Those variables are copied right out of the _example.c_ provided by IJG.ORG. I did not change them. The chapter about `extern` I have read four days ago by the way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solution**: I did not setup OpenCV correctly for using jpeglib. The mistake I made was to link the wrong *.lib-file.

The proper file for linking is `libjpegd.lib`.

Too bad that jpeglib v6.2 is included in OpenCV 2.4.6 instead of v9. The hint to add `HAVE_JPEG` to use jpeglib functions inside OpenCV I ignored completely. Thanks to all who tried solving this issue. **For now the problem is solved.**